# Referenced dll - Does the dll filename matter?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I want to include versioning of dll names for distribution purposes in my own referenced assemblies. For example MyGreat.dll becomes MyGreat.v2.dll .

The namespace in all MyGreat.dll versions (including MyGreat.v.x.x.dll) is MyGreat.

In Visual Studio I can add a reference to either of the file names and it builds without problem. Using the filename MyGreat.dll as the referenced dll, VS works well in debug mode.

When I run VS in debug mode using MyGreat.v.2.dll as the referenced dll I get an error that it cannot find MyGreat.dll or one of its dependencies etc.

I can browse the dll in the visual studio object browser window using either named dll.

I have tried as many combinations and possibilities I can think of including the "or one of its dependencies" and clean the project.

Any ideas?

Edit: fuslogvw results are:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (24/07/2015 @ 6:20:12 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  E:\My Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug\MyProject.vshost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = MyProject.resources, Version=14.0.2.1, Culture=en-GB, PublicKeyToken=d0c57861bf8e7fbf
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/My Projects/MyProject/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = MyProject.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : MyProject, Version=14.0.2.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d0c57861bf8e7fbf.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: E:\My Projects\MyProect\bin\Debug\MyProject.vshost.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: MyProject.resources, Version=14.0.2.1, Culture=en-GB, PublicKeyToken=d0c57861bf8e7fbf
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80070002).
```

EndEdit

Comment: I am not sure if you really create value with this. You can see the version info even with Windows explorer. So why add the version info to the names?

Comment: There are several applications in the project and they frequently reference the same dll. When updating one application, distributing a new version of the dll for that application becomes complicated as they are both added to the GAC. Is there another option?

Comment: "Multiple copies of assemblies with the same name but different version information can be maintained in the global assembly cache." The GAC is designed as the way out of DLL hell. ("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6axd4fx6(v=vs.110).aspx")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not impossible, easy to get wrong however.  Note how you are looking at the wrong Fuslogvw.exe trace.  The setting that matters here is Project > Properties > Application tab in your class library project:

[image]

The assembly name is what other projects that use the assembly embed in their metadata.  Something you can see with ildasm.exe, double-click the manifest:

```
.assembly extern 'ClassLibrary1.v1.2.3.5'
{
  .ver 1:2:3:5
}
```

Anything else you could do to embed the version number in the file name, like renaming the file on disk, will cause the problem you describe.

It is also very, very important that you use a solution with a project reference to the class library.  If you don't and use a file reference then changing the assembly name will break any project that uses the class library, you'd have to remove the reference and add it back.

Re-inventing the GAC is perhaps not the best idea.  Note how it tackles this differently, have a look-see at c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly with Explorer, it stores the assembly in a *folder* that has a name that depends on the version number.